# Not able to access Android Developer console after original creator's account is expired/blocked

Tags: android, google-play, developer-console

An Android Developer account was created using one of employee's Company account at google play store.
That person had added me as admin and also added 2 more developer accounts. 
Now, Original creator has left the company, and his account is locked out. 
Now I or any of our developers are not able to access the developer console.

Kindly help me in this regard, and let me know how to gain access to developer console as We have to update the new version of App to Play Store

Comment: What does 'locked up' mean? Is it banned? Suspended?

Answer (score 1):

Answering for anyone who is still stuck. Only google support team can help in this issue.

Enable the expired account with help of Administrator(off-course after getting all approvals).

Ask google support to transfer the play store account to corporate email account(Do not repeat the mistake of making employee email account as Play Store account).

Ownership of account should be of company/department. Use this account for all play store activities(publishing etc)